# Is every subspace of a infinite-dimensional vector space an intersection of hyperspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

The corollary below is from Hoffman and Kunze's book, *Linear Algebra*.

> **Corollary.** If $W$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, then $W$ is the intersection of
>   $(n-k)$ hyperspaces in $V$.

In the proof, they find $n-k$ linear functionals $f_{i}$ such that $W=\cap_{i=1}^{n-k}\ker (f_{i})$.

I want to know if the following is true: For all proper subspace $W$ of a infinite-dimensional vector space $V$ there are a set of linear functionals $\{f_{i}|i\in I\}$, where $I$ is a set of index such that $W=\cap_{i\in I}\ker (f_{i})$.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: *hyperspaces* should be *hyperplanes* all over the place, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Yes!

Comment: I have a doubt, what about the converse of the lemma? Can you give hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ be a Hamel basis of $W$. Extended this basis to a basis of $V$, let us call it $(w_i)_{i\in I}\cup (v_j)_{j\in J}$. Now for each $j\in J$ defined $f_j(v_j)=1$ and zero elsewhere. It follows that $W=\bigcap_{j\in J} ker(f_j)$.

If you are interested in normed vector space then $W$ need to be a closed subspace and you can mimic the proof using Hahn-Banach.

Comment: You mean, if $W$ is a closed subspace of a normed vector space, the functionals can be chosen to be continuous.

Comment: Is $W \subset ker(f_i)$ also?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  For every $x \notin W$, there is a linear functional $f_x$ on $V$ such that $f_x = 0$ on $W$ and $f_x(x) \ne 0$.  Then $W = \bigcap_{x \notin W} \text{ker}(f_x)$.

Comment: Would this also prove that there exists a family of linear functionals $\{g_i\}$ such that $\text{ker} (g_i) = W$?

Comment: Certainly not $=$ unless $\text{dim}(V/W) = 1$.

Comment: Does that apply in this case where the dimensions are infinite?

Comment: Yes, it does apply.  If $g$ is a linear functional on $V$ and $g(u) \ne 0$, then $\ker(g) + \text{span}(u) = V$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments in this (old) post. Imagine that $V$ was uncountably infinite dimensional. Then, for a non-zero linear functional $g$, since $\text{dim}(V/\text{ker}(g))=1$, $\text{dim}(\text{ker}(g))$ must be also uncountable infinite. But $\text{dim}(\text{span}(u))$ must also de infinite, right?

Comment: No, of course not:  $u$ is a single vector, its span is one-dimensional.

Answer (score 5):

The linear functionals on $V$ which are zero on every element of $W$ are precisely the linear functionals on the quotient $V/W$. So the question reduces to the case that $W = 0$, which follows by the axiom of choice because $V/W$ has a basis.

Without the axiom of choice, the result can be false. For example, it's consistent with ZF that the vector space $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R} / \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}$ has no nonzero linear functionals on it (see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80905/two-questions-about-vector-spaces-absent-ac)).